# How to let system work even after GORM table schema changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using GORM for the purpose of system meta data in database. It however is not expected to be used directly but through cache. The system is entirely dependent on meta data for its inherent working. So, what is expected here is that as far the data resides in cache system should work without any problem even if there happens schema changes in GORM tables that are the ultimate source. Only if the expected data is not present then it should query for database table finally resulting into issue. I know this may not be expected from a production level system but my project is currently in development phase with multiple people involved where changes happens concurrently without other knowing and we don’t want the entire application to go down just because a field name in GORM table was changed.

What can be done to achieve that in GORM? Plus how can we catch any such GORM issue into single place and report it to admin or developer in order to edit mappings of GORM classes?

Answer (score 0):

WOW ! Nice Idea!
For such idea's was grails catch plugin comes in handy ! you can catch domain object

http://grails.org/plugin/cache

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/docs/manual/guide/usage.html

In addition you can use ecahe.plugins for large data support (www.bigdata.com)

```
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.provider_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

**Make your Domain catch able :**

```
class Book {
 …
static mapping = { cache true }
}
class Country {
 …
static mapping = { cache usage: 'read-only' }
}
class Author {
 …
static hasMany = [books:Book]
static mapping = { books cache: true }
}
```

if don't want to crush the application , by overwriting the catch by a new change came from  database domain change you can query it like :

```
def criteria = DomainClass.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.list {
cacheable(true)
}
```

AND MORE ....refrence from Birtbeckwith blog...